# How can I overlay one image over another so that dark background is transparent?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, paste

I have 2 images, test1.jpg and test2.jpg that are RGB images. They have been converted from a 2D numpy array so they are monochrome images. They have the same shape. When I use the `paste` function, I only see one of the images instead of both.

Here are the test1 and test2 jpgs:

[image: test1]

[image: test2].

This is what I get after doing `test1.paste(test2)` and `test1.save('final.jpg')`:

[image: result of paste]

Why is it only showing test2?

Here is my code:

```
im1 = Image.open('test1.jpg')
im2 = Image.open('test2.jpg')
im1.paste(im2)
im1.save('final.jpg')
```

Comment: I thought that paste basically overlays both images. Is that wrong? I want both "arms" to be in the same image, and I thought that's what paste is for.

Comment: "This is what I get after doing test1.paste(test2) and test2.save('final.jpg')"

Are you saving test1 or test2?
The sample code does a different thing from your explanation. The sample should work.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. I think I'm misunderstanding what paste does. Is there a way/function for just combining the contents of the 2 images regardless of the background (I want both arms in one image, so basically just add the white stuff from the 1st image to the 2nd image in the exact same position).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to choose the lighter of your two images at each point with **PIL** [Channel Operations](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageChops.html):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

im1 = Image.open('test1.jpeg')
im2 = Image.open('test2.jpeg')

# Choose lighter of the two images at each pixel location
combined = ImageChops.lighter(im1,im2)
```

[image]

---

Note that you could use `paste()` as you originally intended, but that it will paste all the black as well as the white pixels from `image2` over `image1`. In order to avoid that, you would need to make a mask and only paste where `image2` is non-zero. That might look like this:

```
im1 = Image.open('test1.jpeg')
im2 = Image.open('test2.jpeg')

# Make greyscale mask from image2
mask = im2.convert('L')
mask = mask.point(lambda i: 255 if i>0 else 0)

# Paste image2 into image1 only where image2 has non-black content
im1.paste(im2, mask=mask)
```

I just think the `ImageChops.lighter()` method is simpler.

---

Note that these two methods will give subtly different results. For example, if a pixel is 192 in `image1` and 67 in `image2`, the `ImageChops.lighter()` method will result in 192, whereas the `paste()` method will see there is something in `image2`, and therefore give you the 67. Your choice!

Comment: Thank you! Both of these work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

`paste` is the wrong tool for this job, because it completely replaces the original image with the image you're pasting.  It appears you wanted something closer to the [`blend` function](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.blend) which produces a mix of both images.  Unfortunately this has the side effect of darkening the image, because white blended with black becomes a middle gray; you'll probably want to double the values to compensate.

```
final = Image.blend(test1, test2, 0.5)
final = Image.eval(final, lambda x: 2*x))
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use openCV instead of PIL. OpenCV's imagery is identical to a 2D numpy array, which means you can instead just use basic matrix addition to produce a combined image given "black" pixels are just 0.

```
import cv2 as cv

im1 = cv.imread('test1.jpg')
im2 = cv.imread('test2.jpg')

im3 = im1 + im2
cv.imwrite('test3.jpg', im3)
```

The black pixels remain black, as you're adding 0 to 0, while the filled pixels have the filled values of the two images combined (in this case, 0 + a maximum of 255 given no overlap between the two images)

The resulting image:

[image: Combined form of the supplied test images]

In the case of overlapping non-zero pixels, you may want to apply a 255 ceiling to the arrays, or instead normalize the combined image by the new maximum if that is preferred for your use case.